# How to vertically align a text in a landscape table with images?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, landscape

Here's a working example of my big table with images on it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

% Relevant packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}

% Other packages I'm using
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts,subfig,sidecap} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs,cancel,cleveref,colortbl,csquotes,multirow,listings,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext}
\usepackage[labelfont=sc]{caption}  
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

% Document
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
  \begin{table}[hbt]
     \centering
     \begin{tabular}{ccccc}

        ~ & DJF & MAM & JJA & SON\\

       (A) & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\\

       (B) & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\\

       (C) & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\\

       (D) & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image} & \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\\

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The caption of this very long table.}
    \label{tab:Longtable}
   \end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

As you can see, the text that appears next to the images ((A), (B), (C) and (D)) are not "vertically" aligned or centered with the figures next to them. How could I fix this?

And I'll ask a second question here since it's related to this one. The caption that appears in this table is "Cuadro 1" (Spanish for Table 1). Is there a way to change only this one caption to "Figura 1"(Figure 1)? I'm asking because I actually didn't want to do a table, but I didn't know how to produce this kind of graphics using the figure environment. And since I'm writing a very long document this would be a problem for referencing them later.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: Clarification. My problem with caption is the following. Since it's a table environment the caption is, as intended, a "Table" caption. However, I would love to change this caption to a "Figure" caption, as if I was making a caption on a Figure (but using a table environment).

So the idea would be to produce the same image as above, but instead of "Table X" show "Figure Y" (and get the number Y from the corresponding number of figure instead of the number of table.

Eg: If I had 3 tables and 5 figures in my document, I would like to produce the image above and caption it as "Figure 5" instead of "Table 3".

Comment: Perhaps the easiest fix (in the sense of making the fewest changes to the file you already have) would be adding `\usepackage{adjustbox}` and then changing each `\includegraphics[scale=0.25]` to `\adjincludegraphics[valign=M, scale=0.25]`.  For the language issue, you should add an option like `british` to `babel` and then try `\selectlanguage{british}` after `\begin{landscape}` (the environment will keep the language selection local to that group -- so pay attention to what else is going inside that environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix on the text alignment. The caption problem I have is actually not a language problem, but a "caption" problem. I edited the post for clarification!

Comment: @lanadaquenada with regard to the caption descriptor: LaTeX is not preventing you from using a `tabular` inside a `figure` environment (instead of `table`), when you just need "Figure X" instead of "Table X".

Comment: @jon I just tested your suggestion and it works like a charm, thank you!